# Dictionaries recommendation

Tags: dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [software dictionary](https://superuser.com/questions/75922/software-dictionary)

What are, by today's standards considered most quality dictionaries in terms of volume and usability (*interpret these from common sense; I don't know how to put it better*)?

I'm looking for bi-directional ***dutch/english*** and ***swedish/english*** dictionaries, preferably ones that include as many technical terms from the fields of *mechanical and ocean engineering, as well as computer sciences* as possible.

Can somebody recommend some? I wish to avoid buying based on marketing, only to discover they are worthless (happened before).

*p.s. Google Translate won't cut it. I need them for a trip where I won't have internet access for a longer period of time.*

Comment: I voted to close because this is a request for [a shopping or buying recommendation](http://superuser.com/faq#questions), although I also gave it a +1 because I think it's a good question.

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate, but still, it's a buying recommendation – albeit very specific.

Comment: @slhck - I don't understand. I explicitly said, I'm not looking for online dictionaries (yet half an answers on the link you gave me are such). As for "shopping recommendation" I don't know how to put it so it isn't considered as such. How is "pick me an editor" not a shopping recommendation yet this is? I was just looking for what are quality dictionaries with which people had good experiences with.

Comment: @RandolfRichardson - I don't understand. I explicitly said, I'm not looking for online dictionaries (yet half an answers on the link you gave me are such). As for "shopping recommendation" I don't know how to put it so it isn't considered as such. How is "pick me an editor" not a shopping recommendation yet this is? I was just looking for what are quality dictionaries with which people had good experiences with.

Comment: Also, half of the links in the answers you gave me are dead. The other half doesn't include the dutch/swedish languages.

Comment: I personally did not give you the other answer, and I've explicitly said that it's most probably not a duplicate, due to your specific requirements. What "pick me an editor" are you referring to?

Comment: @slhck - Sorry, I got the names the wrong way round. "pick me an editor" <- I ment it in the way of what's the difference between me asking for a dictionary reccomendation, and someone else asking for an editor reccomendation (which is usually left open as a quetsion). While this one is voted for closure as a shopping or buying recc.

Comment: There is no definitive community decision on the off topicness. I personally have nothing against specific questions such as yours. Questions asking for lists of recommendations are definitely off topic though.

Comment: @slhck - Meh. I bought the paper edition on Amazon this afternoon. Will arrive in a week or so. One more proof that "computer-people" create more problems then they solve. (No offense).